# Turn off layer from LayerList widget on load (ArcGIS JavaScript v3)

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I want to turn off layers from the `LayerList` widget in ArcGIS on load. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a layer property called "[listMode](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-Layer.html#listMode)" that controls if a layer is visible in the LayerList widget. Just set this property to "hide" in the layer constructor.

For example with your layer:

```
var recreationLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Recreation/MapServer", {
"id": "recreationLayer",
"showAttribution": false,
listMode: "hide"
});
```

Comment: Okay, V3 does not seem to have a similar property. But I think I may have misunderstood your question, do you want to hide the layer from appearing in the layer list or just uncheck it? I think you can uncheck it by using the properties of the LayerList dijit